Map Function - Nested Arrays are not supported

Analysis worksheet looks like this right now. Sorry about it not being in markup.
I have a list of months on column A, a count of duplicate aging retro numbers in column B, the duplicate aging case numbers in column C. Column C works and pulls the information from my data table - and I have used column C for my actual report.
Columns E through N (and beyond) are all case numbers that received payments in a particular month for a particular agreement, but the job is to find which ones have gotten duplicates. And we get that through comparing which have gotten retro payments in the same month. Also they seem to be mis-aligned.
The reason for the question is that I'd really like to be able to look in column C, and conditionally format my data table held in another worksheet so that the case numbers in that worksheet can be highlighted; those case numbers are duplicates, they need to be identified, and appropriate corrective action needs to be taken for them. As it stands right now, I'm doing a manual process of filtering the data table for these numbers, and I'd rather not do that.
I wanted to be able to combine all of these numbers in to a single array, so then I could put conditional formatting for my data table to say 'Is the number in my data table in the list of duplicates? If so, format it.

See the source data. You can see for instance, the case number 13138858 appears twice, and has a non zero number in 'retro' and a non zero number in the same month (august). This means it's a duplicate occurrence and I need to track this. However, the number 9556 appears twice, but doesn't meet that criteria; it just means two payments happened to this account during two different periods, none of which were retro payments. The retro units can be 1, -1, or 0; the 'month' units can be 1, -1, or 0, but the only time I care is when retro units and the month units for that particular case number are non-zero during the same month.



Case Number
Retro Start Date
Retro End Date
Retro Units
December
November
October
September
August
July
June
May
April
March




1857460
1-May-24
31-May-24
1





1






1858575
1-Apr-24
30-Apr-24
1






1





1858575
1-Apr-24
30-Jun-24
1




1
1
1





1892043
1-Mar-24
31-Mar-24
1







1




1892043
1-Mar-24
30-Jun-24
1




1
1
1
1




1893337
1-Mar-24
30-Jun-24
1




1
1
1
1




1893337
1-Mar-24
31-Mar-24
1







1




1896176
1-Apr-24
30-Apr-24
1






1





1896176
1-Apr-24
30-Jun-24
1




1
1
1





13102088
1-Jun-24
30-Jun-24
1




1







13102088
1-Jun-24
30-Jun-24
1




1







13138858
1-Jun-24
30-Jun-24
1




1







13138858
1-Jun-24
30-Jun-24
1




1







9556
1-Jan-22
31-May-22
0












9556
1-Jun-21
31-Oct-21
0












12678
1-Mar-24
30-Jun-24
0




0
0
0
0




12678
1-May-24
30-Jun-24
0




0
0






12678
1-Jun-24
30-Jun-24
0




0







13465
1-Mar-24
30-Jun-24
0




0
0
0
0






Try using REDUCE(): =DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",A8#,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,IFNA(TOROW(INDEX(FILTER(July24_Details_1,July24_Details_1[Retro Units]*INDEX(July24_Details_1,,XMATCH(c,July24_Details_1[#Headers]))),,XMATCH(July24_Details_1[[#Headers],[Case Number]],July24_Details_1[#Headers]))),"")))),""),1)

BTW, is it possible to simplify to  FILTER(July24_Details_1[Case Number] instead of CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(July24_Details_1, ... XMATCH(July24_Details_1[[#Headers],[Case Number]],July24_Details_1[#Headers]) in this case?

thank you both and @nkalvi for all for your help. I tried all of the above formulas in my data set and I haven't gotten it exactly right (it's a little too complicated for me right now) and I can't share too much more information without risking improperly disclosing personal information.

As commented above you could try using the following, using one or the other methods:
• Using MAP()


=LET(
 _Head, July24_Details_1[#Headers],
 _Output, MAP(A8#, LAMBDA(a, LET(b, INDEX(July24_Details_1,,XMATCH(a, _Head)),
                    c, XMATCH(July24_Details_1[[#Headers],[Case Number]],_Head),
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(INDEX(FILTER(July24_Details_1, July24_Details_1[Retro Units]*b),,c),""))))),
 _Delim, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(_Output)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Output,",",))+1)),
 IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&_Output,",",_Delim),",",,1),""))


• Or, Using REDUCE()
=LET(
     _Head, July24_Details_1[#Headers],
     DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",A8#,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,
     IFNA(TOROW(INDEX(FILTER(July24_Details_1,July24_Details_1[Retro Units]*INDEX(July24_Details_1,,XMATCH(c,_Head))),,
     XMATCH(July24_Details_1[[#Headers],[Case Number]],_Head))),"")))),""),1))


Edit: Updated Solution Per OP's new edit after posting a solution which was working per the given context in the op:


=LET(
 _Output, BYROW(A23#,LAMBDA(a, LET(
          b, TOROW(XMATCH(a,Table4[#Headers]),2),
          c, CHOOSECOLS(Table4,b),
          d, c*Table4[Retro Units],
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table4[Case Number],d)),""))))),
 _Delim, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(_Output)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Output,",",))+1)),
 IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&_Output,",",_Delim),","),""))


Using MAP():
=LET(
 _Output, MAP(A23#,LAMBDA(a, LET(
          b, TOROW(XMATCH(a,Table4[#Headers]),2),
          c, CHOOSECOLS(Table4,b),
          d, c*Table4[Retro Units],
          TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table4[Case Number],d)),""))))),
 _Delim, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(_Output)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Output,",",))+1)),
 IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&_Output,",",_Delim),","),""))



I'm wondering for identifying duplicates based on

when retro units and the month units for that particular case number are non-zero during the same month

Update 2024-08-05
Since, BYROW(...OR) does not work with older versions of Excel and Conditional formatting does not work when LAMBDA is used, we could create a helper column and use it for Conditional Formatting.
Here I have named the cell containing the formula highlight_duplicate.
=LET(
    month_units, IFERROR(
        BYROW(July24_Details_1[[November]:[June]], LAMBDA(row_, OR(row_))),
        0
    ),
    (July24_Details_1[Retro Units] * month_units) = 1
)



we could express it with is_duplicate =
=LET(
    month_units, IFERROR(
        BYROW(July24_Details_1[[November]:[June]], OR),
        0
    ),
    (July24_Details_1[Retro Units] * month_units) = 1
)

BYROW(July24_Details_1[[November]:[June]], OR) gives TRUE if any of the months had 1.
Here's the result of this step:

(please adjust [November]:[June] to match your data)
Then we could add this in the Name Manager and use it for conditional formatting.
Please let me know if I have misunderstood the logic - I'll delete the answer.

can you explain the logic? I don't follow what the byrow function is aiming to achieve

I'm not sure - would this fail if the retro payments are in separate months? IE if a retro payment occurred in september and one in november, there are 2 retro payments but they are not duplicate payments.

Sure - it is basically checking columns July24_Details_1[[November]:[June]] row by row, by checking each cell within the row has non-zero value. By using OR, result for the row will be 1 if any of the cells had a non-zero value. Please let me know if you want to me illustrate it with screenshot.

To treat one as a duplicate payment, July24_Details_1[Retro Units] also needs to be 1 for that row. So, July24_Details_1[Retro Units] * [If any of the months had a non-zero] needs to be 1.

I tried to isolate just the byrow function - and excel is giving a #NAME error - it can't recognize the OR in the function.

Thank you very much for testing - could you please replace OR section with LAMBDA(row_, OR(row_)) - I'll update the answer to reflect this.

@bdpolinsky you cannot keep on updating your post once there are already answers posted. also if you have different questions you need to raise as a new post. If you are not aware of all these please follow and read meta

Thats not my concern, when you are posting a query you should be aware that multiple edits for a post when answers already posted its not allowed, now another user will come and say that you have something then will you update again. ? If you are not clear about your post then post with more clarity and transparency

I have rolled back your recent updates.
